# App built for Android ARM5TE but device supports ARM5T

Tags: android, opengl-es, arm, android-virtual-device, marmalade

I would like to publish my app on the Android store but I can not get my app to work in the emulator. I cannot figure out why I cannot run my app when so many have published with the same tools as me in the past.

I have downloaded the lastest Android SDK and installed all the API's. There are alot of 2.3.3 devices and my app supposedly supports as far back and API level 3 so I am assuming my app should be working on API level 10. However my app complains that it has been built for ARM5TE and that the device supports ARM5T.

I cannot figure out what this implies and I am able to build with ARM5T but have no idea if that would then mean my app would not work on ARM5TE. I know that most devices are ARM based but I have no idea how many are ARM5TE and ARM5T. I wanted to support the 90% of devices that use the app store that support open GL 2.0.

Comment: ARM5TE is the minimum arm processor android supports. Configure your emulator so it acts like an ARM5TE.

Comment: Oh wow thanks for the info, wow wonder why the Android emulator would default to ARM5T.

Comment: I cannot find any documentation on how to configure my 2.3.3 AVD to use ARM5TE instead of ARM5T, would anyone mind posting a link?

Comment: You can use the `ARM5TE` or even better.  The `ARM5TE` was state of the art in ~2000-2004.  Today, it is a rather old CPU.  I use it, but not for Android.  It is unlikely anyone would make an Android device with an `ARM5TE`, yet alone an `ARM5` only.  The ARM has confusing numbering.  An ARM926 is an ARM5TE.  The *926* is a particular implementation.  For ARM concept wise, a [Pentium 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_4) is like an ARM5TE .  Whereas a *Willamette*, *Northwood*, etc is like an *ARM926*.

Comment: so why are my AVD's emulating ARM5T with no way to change it

Comment: Just as a relief to you. All of my released game, which are made in marmalade, never worked in Android emulator. I had the devices, so I never worried about emulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To improve the ARM architecture for digital signal processing and multimedia applications, DSP instructions were added to the set.[30] These are signified by an "E" in the name of the ARMv5TE and ARMv5TEJ architectures. E-variants also imply T,D,M and I.
>
> The new instructions are common in digital signal processor architectures. They include variations on signed multiply–accumulate, saturated add and subtract, and count leading zeros.

([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#DSP_enhancement_instructions))

Most Android phones released in the last couple of years are based on ARMv7-A, which also supports these DSP instructions.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I am assuming then that I can safely release a ARM5T version or if possible find a way to enable ARM5TE in the emulator and release an ARM5TE version.